# Implement Hilbert Huang Transform

Tags: image-processing, c, software-implementation, empirical-mode-decomposition

I have some programming experiences but am really new to these kind of algorithms. I can find a few source code about implementing HHT, and most of them are written with MATLAB. What I am trying to do:

1. Apply HHT algorithm in detection of image splicing. I want to find object edges in images.
2. Implement this with C/C++ or other efficient languages so it can be used for real project.

But now I don't have any ideas, I don't even know how to design the function prototype for HHT, what its input/output are.

Any help are welcome, thank you

Comment: Way too early to worry about *efficiency* IMO. Make it work, then make it right, *then* make it fast.

Comment: @luserdroog Any idea about making it work?

Comment: No, sorry. That's why I stuck with the platitude. ... If you're going to mimic matlab code, you're going to need a matrix library to start with. Or, can you use matlab itself?

Comment: do u get source code of HHT for image processing???
Its better u can try for BEMD for image instead of EMD

Comment: please tell me how are you using HHT for image splicing detection.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).